# How to Scaffold Controllers In Package Manager Console In vs2019 MVC Core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2019

can Package Manager Console commands be used to build controllers, and if so, where is that documented?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can Package Manager Console commands be used to build controllers

You can try to use [the `aspnet-codegenerator controller` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/tools/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator?view=aspnetcore-3.1#controller-options) to generate controllers, like below.

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller -name TestController -m User -dc MyDbContext --relativeFolderPath Controllers --useDefaultLayout --referenceScriptLibraries
```

Test Result

[image]